# What tax forms should I expect if I exercise and sell options from a company where I am no longer employed?

Tags: united-states, option-exercise, form-w-2, tax-forms

[This article](https://www.dimovtax.com/blog/2018/8/22/taxation-of-incentive-stock-options-iso) suggests that if I were to exercise options that I was granted as part of an ISO grant and then sell them in the same year, the bargain element would be recorded in my W-2 form. What happens if I do these transactions in a year when I am not employed by the company? Will I receive a W-2 anyway with just this compensation? Or will I receive some other tax form?